# Github Markdown for different font colors

Tags: github

Except using CSS and git diff is there a way to change the font color of the text in Github Readme or Comments.

Comment: Are you asking if you can control the coloring of the README as it's displayed by GitHub and in issue and pull request comments?

Comment: No I am asking  is there a markdown to control the text font color in any comment or Readme or anywhere where Markdown are applicable.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub does not allow you to control the font color of anything that's rendered on a page, whether that's a README, an issue comment, a pull request comment, or elsewhere.  There are a couple reasons for this.

First of all, spammers and other people trying to engage in abuse will try to hide text by using a font color that's identical or very similar to the page background.  GitHub does not want to encourage spam and abuse.

Second, allowing users to set the font color creates accessibility problems, since users can set fonts that are difficult for some people to see due to low contrast.  GitHub is legally and ethically required to consider accessibility in its interface.

Third, it prevents GitHub from creating new styles or features like a potential dark mode.  Colors that might look fine on a light background would be impossible to see clearly on a dark background.

Even CSS doesn't work here; GitHub filters all content rendered on the interface to strip out anything that might be harmful or problematic.

Comment: Okay, Thank you so much for this elaborated information @bk2204